# Perform Union/OR Operation between where clause and having Clause

Tags: sql, union, where-clause, having, having-clause

I am working on implementation for a SQL which should display results with Union operation between Where and Having Clause. 
For example,

```
Select * from table where col1= 'get' group by col2 (OR/UNION) having avg(col3) >30 . This is not valid but trying to give use a case
```

The purpose of the sql statement is to return result set which satisfies both where and having conditions.

Lets say I have a table1, has with col1, col2, col3, col4 and large data in the table. Now, There is a use case in which user wants to see results when selects filters with specific crtieria col1 ='Y', avg(col2) >10, avg(col3*col4) =30 in filters list. Now, I have to create a criteria, such that, I should return all results which satisfies col1 ='Y' OR avg(col2) >10 OR avg(col3*col4) =30 , like we do in where clause with OR operator but here we have both where clause and having clause –

```
Like, the below query
```

resultset1 <= select * from table1 where col1= 'get';
resultset2 <= select * from table1 group by col2 having avg(col3) >30

final results = resultset1+ resultset2
Do any one have better approach or ideas in implementing such scenario?

Lets say I have filters combinations as below

col1 =23
OR
avg(col2) >30
AND
avg(col3) =10
OR
avg(col1) <10
AND
col2 =10

I need to display results satisfying these criteria in SQL

Comment: This query is invalid in most RDBMS because you are doing `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY` query.  Please update your question with sample data and expected output.

Comment: Show us the table structure, sample data and expected output to let us help you better.

Comment: Question says *where and having* but query says  *where or having* so which one is correct

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve with this SQL. Just describe a problem you try to solve.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I know the query is invalid but I am trying to make a case to explain the problem.

Comment: I have a table1, has with col1, col2, col3, col4 and large data in the table. Now, There is a use case in which user wants to see results when selects filters with specific crtieria col1 ='Y', avg(col2) >10, avg(col3*col4) =30 in filters list. Now, I have to create a criteria, such that, I should return all results which satisfies col1 ='Y' OR avg(col2) >10 OR avg(col3*col4) =30 , like we do in where clause with OR operator but here we have both where clause and having clause

Comment: Even after your edits, you still seem to be confused about how `GROUP BY` works.  Please show clear input and expected output, as you have not done this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in general I understand the criteria as they are not mutually exclusive. But I want to treat them as mutually exclusive and return combine list. GROUP BY if needed can be ignored. But I want to combine where clause and having clause results like OR not like AND condition

Comment: @Prdp OR operation between having & where clauses -

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what do you want from this quasi SQL. I guess you need to select records with two conditions `col1= 'get'` AND /OR ? `having avg(col3) >30`. So here is the solution:

```
Select * from table 
 where (col1= 'get')
 OR 
 col2 in (SELECT col2 FROM table GROUP BY col2 HAVING avg(col3) >30)
```

If you need both conditions where true then replace OR with AND.

If you need to count AVG only for `col1 = 'get'` then add this condition into the subquery:

```
Select * from table 
 where (col1= 'get')
 OR 
 col2 in (SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE (col1= 'get') 
                      GROUP BY col2 
                      HAVING avg(col3) >30)
```

Comment: In this case, Having avg(col3) >30 is applied on top filtered list based on col1 = 'get' but I need results which displays both avg(col3) >30 and col1='get' . where one uses where-clause and other uses having clause.

Comment: @TechJump the first query from my answer with `OR` actually do this.

Comment: Thanks valex let me try it and I am also concerned about the performance as there is huge data, having multiple like conditions might impact performance?

Comment: Lets say I have filters combinations as below

col1 =23 OR avg(col2) >30 AND avg(col3) =10 OR avg(col1) <10 AND col2 =10

I need to display results satisfying these criteria in SQL

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT <resultset1>   --resultset based on a WHERE clause
UNION
SELECT <resultset2>   --resultset based on HAVING`

In general, if you want a union of resultsets, use ... UNION.

Using OR in a condition is equivalent to UNION (because the UNION operator is the relational algebra equivalent of logical disjunction), but it requires the scope of the involved conditions to be identical.

In this case, this is impossible because a HAVING condition applies not to the table mentioned in the SELECT, but instead to an intermediate table that is "silently" created by the GROUP clause.  This is inevitably so because things like AVG,SUM,... only make sense if it is also determined ***which set of rows*** must be used to compute the AVG,SUM,... over, and that is what the GROUP BY specification does.

EDIT

In SQL, UNION comes in distinct flavours, UNION DISTINCT and UNION ALL.  One eliminates duplicates, the other won't.  If you want the exact same behaviour as OR, you'll obviously need the one that eliminates duplicates from its result set.

Comment: If I follow this approach, what is the impact on performance?

Comment: Performance is a function of (a) the nature of the filtering predicates (b) the nature of the physical design of the db (which indexes etc.) and (c) the specific features built into the optimizer of the specific version of the specific DBMS you are using.  And most of the times also (d) which specific statistics are being collected about the db.  Do you seriously expect anything like a firm "none" as an answer to this unanswerable question ?